# Compilation error when adding dependency: com.google.firebase:firebase-core

Tags: android, firebase, cordova, gradle, push-notification

I'm trying to modify the Cordova plugin [Phonegap Plugin Push plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) to include `FirebaseAnalytics`. To do so, I added `firebase-core` as a dependency in plugin.xml:

```
<framework src="com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8"/>
```

If I add this plugin to a new project (no other plugins installed) and try to compile, I get the error:

```
Failed to notify dependency resolution listener.
> The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 16.2.0. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.
> The library com.google.firebase:firebase-iid is being requested by various other libraries at [[16.0.0,16.0.0]], but resolves to 17.0.3. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.
```

I don't know where does this conflict come from. I tried to search for `play-services-basement` and `firebase-iid` in the project, but there were no matches. I didn't see them in the `gradle` dependency list either.

How can I fix this? What's the best way to find where does this conflict come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by updating the version of "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:" to 17.5.0, I was using 17.0.0

Answer (score 1):

Go to platform/android/project.properties then specify the version you want to use.
Instead of using "+"
`com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.+`
use specified version
`com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.6.0`